# mySQL Join Query in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am new to cakePHP and i am reading the manuels and have bought the book, i have come across a issue and need some assistance.

At the moment i query my DB like this (this is the whole class) :

```
<?php

class TapplicantController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        $this->set('page_title', 'Dashboard');

        $tapplicant = $this->Tapplicant->query("SELECT tapplicant.AppID, tapplicant.AppIPAddress, tapplicant.AppAffID, tapplicant.AppDate, tapplicant.FirstName, tapplicant.LastName, tapplicant.Email, tapplicant.AppDomain, toutcome.AffCommission FROM tapplicant INNER JOIN toutcome ON tapplicant.AppID=toutcome.AppID LIMIT 0,15 ");

        $this->set('tapplicant', $tapplicant );     


    }
}
```

and then i display it like this and it works fine :

```
<?php foreach ($tapplicant as $tapplicant) : ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AppID']; ?></td> 
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AppAffID']; ?></td> 
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['FirstName']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['LastName']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['Email']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AppDate']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AppDomain']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AffCommission']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is i have Inner Joined 2 tables and its not working , i get the following error : Undefined index: AffCommission

Comment: use <td><?=$tapplicant['toutcome']['AffCommission']; ?></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `query()` to retrieve data in CakePHP unless you really can't write the query using the [Cake way](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). To use joins in Cake your query should look something like this:-

```
$tapplicant = $this->Tapplicant->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Tapplicant.*',
            'Toutcome.*'
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'toutcome',
                'alias' => 'Toutcome',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID')
            )
        ),
        'limit' => 15
    )
);
```

The resulting array should then be indexed by the model aliases so `$tapplicant['tapplicant']['AffCommission'];` should be something like `$tapplicant['Toutcome']['AffCommission'];`. The easiest way to debug this would be to look at what the returned array is so use either `print_r($tapplicant)` or `debug($tapplicant)` in your code to look at what's returned.

The [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) would probably make it even simpler as long as you associate your models correctly.

You're not using [CakePHP naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) which you really should be otherwise you're going to have a lot of difficulties working with Cake. I'd recommend you read through the online docs from the start before jumping in at the deep end!

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer. after using the above and then running a debug, it does not join the tables.

Comment: @MaxPayneUK I've updated my answer so that it specifically includes the fields from both tables (forgot to include that before). If that doesn't fix it then you need to look at the query being generated by Cake and try running it directly against the database to see if it works. If you've not already got it installed the DebugKit plugin will help (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/tree/2.2).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'toutcome',
        'alias' => 'Toutcome',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID')
         )
);

$options['fields'] = array(
    Tapplicant.AppID, 
    Tapplicant.AppIPAddress, 
    Tapplicant.AppAffID, 
    Tapplicant.AppDate, 
    Tapplicant.FirstName, 
    Tapplicant.LastName, 
    Tapplicant.Email, 
    Tapplicant.AppDomain, 
    Toutcome.AffCommission
);

$options['limit'] = 15;

$tapplicant = $this->Tapplicant->find('all', $options);
```